# c++ recursion find the smallest element in the array of strings

Tags: c++, recursion

I need to find the subscript of the least string in the array using recursion and if the array has no elements to examine, return -1.
Here is what I came up so far but it does not work.

```
int leastElement(string a[], int n)
{
    if(n == 1)
        return 0;



    if(a[0] > a[n])
        a[0] = a[n];

    return leastElement(a, n-1);
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What is not working? More info please

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a homework solution site.

Comment: what is the smallest element in the array of strings? Lexicographical order?

Comment: Hint: you're not saving the subscripts during the execution, you're saving the minimal string at the first place instead

Comment: The most obvious problem is that you're not handling the "array has no elements" case. If `n` is 0, you're going to recurse to `-1` and so on until you wrap around the int…

Comment: texasbruce, altough the question is indeed from homework, I am trying to understand how recursion works and learn from this example and not to acquire solution for my home work. Do you think I am at blame here because I try to understand ? I mean I do not know what else to do, I cant figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

```
int leastElement(string a[], int n)
{
    if (n <= 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    int k = 1 + leastElement(a + 1, n - 1);
    if (a[0] < a[k]) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return k;
    }
}
```

Comment: Small comment: in case of several minimums, it will return the last one

Answer (score 1):

One of the key concepts to recursion is next recursion carries the previous recursion's state. For example, a linked list is a perfect object for recursion because the next recursion is usually based on the previous linked list linking.

In this case, array requires a start and end point to define an array. Therefore you need to carry the start and end index of your array.

```
int leastElement(int arr[], int start, int end) {
  if (start >= end -1) {
    return start;
  }
  else {
    int subLeastElement = leastElement (arr, start + 1, end);
    if (arr[start] <= arr[subLeastElement]) {
      return start;
    }
    else {
      return subLeastElement;
    }
  }
}

//This provides a simplified start point
int leastElement(int arr[], int n) {
    return leastElement(arr, 0, n);
}
```

Working example here:

[coliru code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b23a74424f3491a)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    char minimum(char a, char b)
    {
        if(a < b)
            return a;
        else
            return b;

    }
    char leastElement(string a, int n)
    {
        if(n == -1)
            return -1;
        if(n == 0)
            return a[0];
        return minimum(a[n],leastElement(a, n-1));
    }
    int main()
    {
        string a= "AaHelloz";
        //cout<<a;
        cout<<leastElement(a,a.length()-1);

        return 0;
    }
```

This is the simple code to get minimum character in string through recursion.

Comment: OP is asking about strings, but this is easily transferable.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion depth will be proportion to `n`, you could instead split the array in half at each level:

```
int leastElement(string a[], int n) {
       if (n <= 0)
          return -1;  // paranoid about empty array
       if (n == 1)
          return 0;
       const int left = leastElement(a, n/2);
       const int right = leastElement(a + n/2, n - n/2);
       if (left == -1) // paranoia again
          return right + n/2;
       if (right == -1)
          return left;
       return (a[left] < a[right + n/2]) ? left : right + n/2;
}

int main() {
  string a[] = {
    "ugl", "nvk", "akl", "ngl", "qal", "fgp", 
    "rjv", "kln", "ahf", "lak", "vjh",
    "sdf", "lak", "lmc", "lhf", "wer"
  };
  const int i = leastElement(a, 16);
  cout << i; // returns 8 "ahf"
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Splitting in half won't change the runtime, it just obfuscates your code. In fact, it will probably slow down the execution because of excessive arithmetics on each step

Comment: Probably slower, but it will *not* blow the stack frame for a large array. Not obfuscated at all -- the least of the least of each half is the string you are looking for. Optimal runtime is O(n) which this is.

Comment: You're right, I misread your answer and thought you're referring to time complexity

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to recursively visit every string in the list, then as the recursion unwinds, you check each one with the current least.

```
int leastElement(std::string a[], int n) {
    if(n == 0)
        return -1;

    int least = leastElement(a, n - 1);
    if (least > -1 && a[least] < a[n - 1]) {
        return least;
    }
    return n - 1;
}
```

Comment: You should compare `a[least + 1]` with `a[n - 1]` - see @XiaotianPei answer.

Comment: @icepack, how does that improve this? Does this one miss something by not comparing `least + 1`?

Comment: Of course, that's the most important part. Your `least` index is relevant to a subarray which starts at a position shifted by 1 with respect to the original array. Thus in order to compare it to original indexes, you need to adjust it appropriately

Comment: @icepack, I think that's fixed now, The problem wasn't with `least + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be written

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int leastElement( const std::string a[], int n )
{
    if ( n <= 0 ) return - 1;

    int i = 1 + leastElement( a + 1, n - 1 );

    return i == 0 || !( a[i] < a[0] ) ? 0 : i;
}


int main()
{
    std::string a[] = { "C", "D", "A", "E" };

    int i = leastElement( a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );
    std::cout << i << ": " << a[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2: A
```

Pay attention to this condition

```
!( a[i] < a[0] )
```

Usually such functions have to return the first least element if there are several equal least elements and this condition provides this requirement.

To decrease the depth of the recursion you can split the array into two parts. Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int leastElement( const std::string a[], int n )
{
    if ( n <= 0 ) return -1;
    if ( n == 1 ) return 0;

    int i = leastElement( a, n / 2 );
    int j = n / 2 + leastElement( a + n / 2, n - n / 2 );

    return !( a[j] < a[i] ) ? i : j;
}

int main()
{
    std::string a[] = { "C", "D", "A", "E" };

    int i = leastElement( a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );
    std::cout << i << ": " << a[i] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be the same as above

```
2: A
```

Comment: what's the purpose of `i == 0` ?

Comment: @icepack A recursive call of the function can return -1.  It is called like int i = 1 + leastElement( a + 1, n - 1 ); Thus 1 + -1 will be 0.

Comment: This case is covered already in the return condition

Comment: @icepack Without this condition the overal condition looks confusing !( a[0] < a[0] )